# apt-get update not working as azure custom script extension

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, apt

I'm deploying linux ubuntu 16.04 LTS VMSS using Azure ARM template with custom script extension. Content of customscript.sh:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential -y
...
```

but it fails at this update step itself with error:

```
Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease into data and signature failedE: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

When I login to the VM and perform apt-get update, it runs successfully.

ARM Template for deployment of Linux VMSS using Custom Script Extension:

```
 "virtualMachineProfile": {
          "extensionProfile": {
            "extensions": [              
              {
                "name": "Custom Deployment",
                "properties": {
                  "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
                  "typeHandlerVersion": "2.1",
                  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                  "protectedSettings": {
                    "commandToExecute": "[concat('/bin/bash customscript.sh')]",
                    "fileUris": [
                      "[parameters('scriptToExecuteLinux')]"
                    ]
                  },
                  "type": "CustomScript"
                }
              },
            }
         ......
       }
```

Please let me know if I'm performing any step incorrectly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication

Comment: Yes, but the problem doesn't arise when I perform apt-get update after logging into the VM, why does it fail when ran through customscript extension

Answer (score 0):

I have basically no experience with azure but it could be that you run the script as the wrong user, if you are running this as root, maybe try running it as a normal user. If you're running this script as a user, maybe try running it as root.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issues in your code
1. I think you are not correctly using the concat function. There is only one argument
2. Cross check that you have all the key value pairs as per the extension schema mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

For more detailed errors, please check the file /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/stderr, you might find some answers.

When you ran it manually did you try `/bin/bash script.sh` or `sh script.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am 3 years behind, but you can't run apt-get update as the first command in a Virtual Machine Scale Set because Azure does that by default.

Since you are using a Scale Set VM, the workflow is a VM is provisioned, apt-get update is ran, then the custom script is downloaded and executed.

What I think is happening, is your VM instance is running two apt-get update commands in two different processes at the same time. You can only run apt-get update in one process to avoid race conditions and other multi-thread problems.

The lock can't be acquired for your custom script, so you are probably getting a "Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 870 (python3) E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/"

The solution is simple. Just remove apt-get update because the VM is already executing that when it is provisioned/updated.